# Best practise custom paging SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, pagination

I'm got trouble with paging on SQL server 2005 which run query 2 times (get data and total rows). My demo proc below which base on Northwind database. Please help me to how to get total rows without query again.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchEmployees] 
     @search nvarchar(4000)
    ,@orderBy varchar(200)
    ,@PageSize int
    ,@PageIndex int 
    ,@TotalRowsNumber int output
AS
DECLARE @PageLowerBound int
DECLARE @PageUpperBound int

SET @PageLowerBound = @PageSize * @PageIndex
SET @PageUpperBound = @PageSize + @PageLowerBound

--Default order by to first column
IF (@OrderBy is null or LEN(@OrderBy) < 1)
BEGIN
    SET @OrderBy = 'EmployeeID DESC'
END

-- SQL Server 2005 Paging
declare @SQL as nvarchar(4000)
declare @SQLCOUNT as nvarchar(4000)
declare @Param as nvarchar(500)

SET @SQL = 'WITH PageIndex AS ('
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' SELECT  '
IF @PageSize > 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' TOP ' + convert(nvarchar, @PageUpperBound)
END

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @OrderBy + ') as RowIndex '
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' ,EmployeeID'
SET @SQL = @SQL + ', LastName'
SET @SQL = @SQL + ', FirstName'
SET @SQL = @SQL + ', Title'

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM employees'
IF Len(@Search) > 0 
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' ' + @Search
END
SET @SQL = @SQL  + ') SELECT '
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' EmployeeID'
SET @SQL = @SQL + ', LastName'
SET @SQL = @SQL + ', FirstName'
SET @SQL = @SQL + ', Title'
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM PageIndex  '
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE RowIndex > ' + convert(nvarchar, @PageLowerBound)

IF @PageSize > 0
BEGIN
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND RowIndex <= ' + convert(nvarchar, @PageUpperBound)
END

--Get Row Count
SET @SQLCOUNT = 'SELECT @TotalRowsNumber  = count(EmployeeID)
                    FROM employees' 
SET @Param = N'@Search nvarchar(2000),@TotalRowsNumber INT OUTPUT'
IF LEN(@Search) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQLCOUNT = @SQLCOUNT + @Search 
END
exec sp_executesql @SQL
exec sp_executesql @SQLCOUNT, @Param,@Search=@Search,@TotalRowsNumber = @TotalRowsNumber OUT
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this, See it as an example

```
CREATE Procedure usp_GetBookings
@pageIndex int,
@pageSize tinyint
as
;with CTE as 
(
Select Distinct ROW_NUMBER() over( order by ssi.SSItineraryID desc) as seq ,Count(*) over() as TotalRow,ssi.SSItineraryID 
 from SightSeeingItinerary as ssi
)

select * from CTE
where cte.seq  between  (@pageIndex-1) * @pageSize+1 and ((@pageIndex-1) * @pageSize +(@pageSize))
```

Comment: Thanks your response. I'm using the same logic as your recommend! It works well. :D